# Trying to learn about namespaces and it does not seem to work, class is not found

Tags: php, namespaces

I just do not seem to be able to wrap my head around why this does not seem to be working. I'm trying to learn about namespaces, and going from the book to the computer, thinking this would just be easy, I've been occupied with this for the last one and a half hour now and just do not get what I am doing wrong.

**Here's the deal.**

I'm running MAMP Pro on my MacBook from a folder on my desktop called 'learning-php'.
In side this folder there are two files.

/Index.php
/Classes/Person.php

These two files look like this:

**File**: index.php

```
<?php

use Classes\Person;

$person = new Person();

?>
```

**File**: Classes/Person.php

```
<?php 

namespace Classes;

class Person 
{
//code goes here...
}

?>
```

This results in this error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Classes\Person' not found in /Users/John/Desktop/learning-php/index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Users/John/Desktop/learning-php/index.php on line 5

Comment: Is that all there is? You'll need an autoloader as well to load the missing classes for example.

Comment: Seeking for a magic... PHP doesn't work that way.

Comment: I thought I did not need to use the include when doing the namespace thingy? I thought I would just use the 'use' and it would work automatically? Is autoloading what makes this happen in the background, you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `include`, it will pull the entire file into the file you are incuing it into so you could make an instance of the class anywhere after your `include` statement. You will need to have a way to find the full file path to the file however, since it is not going to take it from the root of your application.

Documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

```
include '/Users/John/Desktop/learning-php/Classes/Person.php';
$person = new Person();
```

Comment: That just results in a lot more errors saying the file does not exist.

Comment: Make sure you use the full file path to the file, I've added the full file path that you posted in your original post

Comment: This does work: include __DIR__ . '/Classes/Person.php'; ... But what would the point being of using the namespace / use statements then? Maybe I've misunderstood something here?

Comment: @EnergyStar Namespaces for example help you avoid clashes between classes with the same names. You are looking for an autoloader.

Comment: spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    $class = str_replace('\\', '/', $class);
    include __DIR__ . '/'. $class . '.php';
});

Comment: That worked for me. Thanks. I misunderstood the usage of namespaces and seemed to mix it up with autoloading. Thanks for the feedback, and actually helping. StackOverflow seem to be flooded with way to many elitist.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Using something like this will allow you to auto-load the classes. To test just include it in the top of your PHP page after declaring the namespace.

```
<?php

namespace Test;

spl_autoload_register(function($className){

    include '../'.$className.'.php';

});

$obj = new Test(); //this loads from Test/Foo/Bar/Test.php
```